# How can I store generic types in a cache so as to avoid unchecked casts on retrieval?

Tags: java, generics, caching

Have to erase some of the details of this, but basically I'm trying to cache the result of an expensive operation which returns a collection of objects, but the types of these individual objects are not known at compile-time (only a base class).

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static final Map<Integer,Collection<? extends SomeBaseClass>> theCache = new HashMap<Integer,Collection<? extends SomeBaseClass>>();

    public <T extends SomeBaseClass> Collection<T> theMethod(Class<T> theClass, int index)
    {
        if (theCache.containsKey(index))
        {
            return (Collection<T>) theCache.get(index);
        }
        else
        {
            Collection<T> result = someExpensiveOperation(theClass, index);
            theCache.put(index, result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Here the cache retrieval is an unchecked cast because the code is just taking it on trust that the class argument passed into the method by the caller is compatible (should be identical) with the one passed by the earlier invocation which created the object in the cache in the first place.

Is there some way or some design pattern to cache the actual class together with the object itself, so that this unchecked cast can be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no direct support for this behaviour.

If you cache contains individual elements, you can use `Class.cast()`, it throws a `ClassCastException` in the case of mismatch:

```
private Map<Integer, ?> cache = ...;

public <T> T get(Integer id, Class<T> c) {
    return c.cast(cache.get(id));
}
```

In the case of cached collections it would be more complex. If you actually want to avoid unchecked cast, you can create a new collection and populate it via `Class.cast()`:

```
Collection<T> result = ...;
for (Object o: theCache.get(index)) 
    result.add(theClass.cast(o));
return result;
```

Other approaches include, for example, creating a "checked" view of collection using Guava's `Collections2.transform()`:

```
public class Cast<T> implements Function<Object, T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public Cast(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T apply(Object in) {
        return type.cast(in);
    }
}
```

.

```
return Collections2.transform(theCache.get(index), new Cast<T>(theClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to handle this. Here's what I'd do - create a Collection class that stores its element type:

```
class TypedList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    TypedList(Class<T> type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

And make sure that someExpensiveOperation() uses this class to return its results. That way, you'll be able to query the type when you retrieve the cache item.

Comment: That's not useful with a static cache.